# Julia distribute function: specifying distributed dimension

Tags: julia, distributed

I'm interested in distributing an MxN integer array across p workers. Is there a way to specify which dimension gets distributed? In particular, I want to keep the number of rows M fixed and distribute over N columns. In my case M > N (I have a term-document matrix with vocabulary of size M and number of documents N).

By default, Julia appears to distribute over the dimension that has the largest size, which doesn't work for my application (I want to distribute over the documents and not the vocabulary). Is there a way to control which dimension gets distributed?

Answer (score 1):

`SharedArray` constructor has a `pids` optional parameter which maps elements to processes (see [documentation](https://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.5/stdlib/parallel/#shared-arrays)).

So, an MxN matrix can be initialized with the following code:

```
# a helper function which might be useful in other contexts
function balancedfill(v,n,b)
    d,r = divrem(n,b)
    return v[[repeat(1:r,inner=d+1);repeat(r+1:b,inner=d)]]
end

# N,M = size(mat)
pidvec = repeat(balancedfill(1:nprocs(),N,nprocs()),inner=M)

sharedmat = SharedArray{Float64}((N,M); pids=pidvec)
```

This creates a Float64 shared array, with columns balanced between processes. Float64 can be replaced by the element-type needed. With a little change (switching `inner` with `outer` and `N` with `M` in `pidvec` creation) a row-wise distributed array can be created.